# Want help in editing my own answer

Tags: discussion

What should I do if I want someone's help to edit my answer? For eg: If I don't know the expansion of some mathematical series , whom should I ask help?

Comment: You can try it here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics